# How can user allow to “undo” the programmatic insertion of text into a textarea?

Tags: javascript, textarea

I have a textarea and a button. Clicking the button causes text to be inserted into the textarea.

Is there a way to allow a user to press Ctrl/Cmd+z to undo the insertion of text and revert the textarea to its previous state?

---

I found original [question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13597007/how-can-i-undo-the-programmatic-insertion-of-text-into-a-textarea) already but it's  quite old and most upvoted answer won't work anymore for any major browser. What's 2017 approach for this?

Comment: Why not adding a bounty to the other question, saying that the answers are not relevant anymore and you are looking for a "2017 approach"?

Comment: @Dekel I didn't think about it, I just made a bounty +500!

Comment: And you got my vote on several other answers you wrote :)

Comment: why not just replace the added text with "", sounds like enough for your use case