# Cannot undo changed keydown event after set customized event listener

Tags: javascript, dom-events, keydown, preventdefault, undo

Here is the demo. For example, I want to get a <kbd>b</kbd> after I key down <kbd>a</kbd>, like this:

```js
const text = document.getElementById('text');
text.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
  if (e.key === 'a') {
    e.preventDefault();
    const start = e.target.selectionStart;
    const end = e.target.selectionEnd;
    e.target.value = `${e.target.value.substring(0, start)}b${e.target.value.substring(end)}`;

    e.target.selectionStart = start + 1;
    e.target.selectionEnd = start + 1;
  }
})
```

```html
<textarea id="text"></textarea>
```

But I cannot undo (<kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd>) the input after I type <kbd>a</kbd>, as the <kbd>b</kbd> is just staying there and I cannot go to the state before.

My question is how to store the state before I type <kbd>a</kbd>? So like before (without the event listener), I can press <kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>z</kbd> to undo my input.

Comment: Or is there a way to store a state every after a period of time? So I can undo to history state after setting this event listener.

Comment: This HTML isn’t valid. Tags cannot be opened after `<body>`, and `<head>` is missing.

Comment: Possible [duplicate](https://google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+js+cannot+undo+after+programmatically+changing+text) of [Is it possible to edit a text input with javascript and add to the Undo stack?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27027833/4642212) or [How can I “undo” the programmatic insertion of text into a textarea?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13597007/4642212). Unfortunately, this is currently difficult to achieve in a cross-browser and cross-platform way.

Comment: @Simon, I am sure it is valid on my browser. Thank you for the links and they are very helpful. I will try them one by one. I think it's ok even if it just works fine on Chrome. ( But what do you mean by saying it is difficult in a cross-browser/platform environment?

Comment: If you read the comments in these links, there’s a lot of discussion about incompatibility with Firefox and a linked bug report; you can also visit the [documentation for `document.execCommand`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/execCommand), see that it’s deprecated, and has had various incompatibilities in all browsers and platforms. See also [`execCommand()` is now obsolete, what's the alternative?](/q/60581285/4642212) _“I am sure it is valid on my browser”_ — It may work, but it isn’t _valid_. You can [validate your HTML](https://html5.validator.nu/).

Comment: Well. Anyway I just want to give a minimal demo and avoid other useless information here. It's not from the real codes. Thank you anyway for these possible solutions